Relationship between Magentic poles and electrons as per Lenz's Law
When reviewing lenz's law of electromagentism, it occured to me that their might be a deeper relationship between electron and magnetism.
My assumption is that since since magnetic field is just an electric field in a another frame of reference, the north or south pole of a magnet might correspond to an electron. Running a magnet next to a wire may induce a current paralell or opposite to the direction of the magnet flow and lenz's law may just be a complicated wording of this phenomenon in terms of the magnetic field.
Lenz's law state that direction of current is such that the magnetic field of the current opposes the change. That is why a magnet is paired with a coil. Because the magnetic field produced between the two has the greatest surface area with one another. This means that the north (or south) pole isnt pushing electron.
But still their must be a relationship between these two.
Another question that seems like another aspect of this. Is it the moving magnet that produces the magnetic field of the wire which induces the current or does the moving magnet induce a current which produces the magnetic field of the wire

since magnetic field is just an electric field in a another frame of reference That’s not true, although it’s a widespread misunderstanding. A pure magnetic field in one frame is not a pure electric field in any other inertial frame. The fields mix under Lorentz transformations, but never completely transform into the other one. So you cannot just wish away magnetism as being due to a poor choice of reference frame.

What we can say about Faraday's law and electron movement in magnetic field is the connection this law has with Lorentz Force. Please check my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/833117/364663 about this topic
